# Segmentation fault using simpl html dom file get html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

using php library simple_html_dom i'm looping through a list of urls as dom and for each of these i try to find a string, if i find it i save the url in an array otherwise i go to the next cycle, returning the urls array at the end.
The script takes something of the order of some sec for each url.
after some loop the script get stuck on the $dom->load($url) line inside file get html throwing a segmentation fault, the number of loops varies on different urls lists.
I tried to isolate the call at load($url) in a test script working only on the url in which the looping script get stuck but the test script end with no errors (but i can't check the print_r of the dom because my firefox crashes if i try to view page source).
I'm working on a LAMP server. Here is the code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("max_execution_time", "300");
ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
set_time_limit(100);

$urlArray = array();

foreach($urlArray as $url){
    $found = false;
    $dom = file_get_html($url);
    foreach(( $dom->find('target')) as $caught){
        array_push($link, $caught);
        $found = true
    }
    if($trovato){
        return $link;
    }else{
        echo "not found";
    }
}
```

thx for any help

Comment: So you are getting both a segmentation fault in PHP and a crash in Firefox? That's what I call a bad day... *(BTW, that's not your real code, is it?)*

Comment: The problem is the segmentation fault, i think firefox crashes just cause displaying the whole domDocument is just too much data and i don't rly need to do it so it's not much significant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well its common problem, here is a bug http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/103/.
Add this lines before your `if` statement:

```
$dom->clear();
unset($dom);
```

Mostly you will not see any segfaults after that. But if you parse several thousands urls (like me :)) than you might meet it again. So my solution is - open simple_html_dom.php file, and comment all lines between 146 and 149.

```
 function clear()
 {
   /*
   $this->dom = null;
   $this->nodes = null;
   $this->parent = null;
   $this->children = null;
   */
 }
```

**UPDATE:** also if you comment this lines - your memory consumption will increase each parsing iteration

Comment: Instead of commenting those lines, as per the bug, it says to unset those variables. More info: http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/103/

Comment: @Devaroop, yes! But it didn`t help me i still got segfault after unset. Commenting is the only way that help me with this problem.